# How to create a SOAP Web service with .NET(C#) with a Java based Client?

Tags: java, .net, web-services, soap

I need to create a SOAP Web Service in C#.
I've done this in the past in Java with eclipse, but couldn't really find something that is SOAP specific when creating a new Web Service project in VS2008.
I need some kind of guidance on how to start this.

Also, the intended client will be implemented in Java,
are there known compatibility issues with this?

Thanks

Answer (score 2):

It doesnt matter what the client is, that's the nature of web services (interopable communications).

You can either create a 'legacy' ASP.NET Web Service (ASMX), or a WCF Service.

By default, ASMX web services (or WCF Services with regular HTTP endpoints) transmit XML over HTTP (SOAP).

If you're writing something from scratch, consider WCF over ASMX - more flexbility and security.

Comment: See here for an interoperability guide on WCF standards:
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms734776.aspx